# SQL 2012 Computed Column Foreign Key Exclusive Or With Ten Other Tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have eleven tables.

Call one of them the Parent table, and the other ten are Child tables, perhaps ChildA, ChildB, etc through ChildJ

Consider the Parent table to be abstracting a piece of electronics. Every piece of electronics has some common columns, like a name, but each different type of electronic device has widely differing properties. The columns needed to represent a TV are greatly different than, say, a cell phone.

The parent may have one and only one child that exists in one of the Child tables, but will not be associated with more than one.

Ergo, if Parent has a ChildA, it won't have a ChildB through ChildJ.

The way that I have currently implemented this is through one "ChildType" column, one "ChildId" field, and ten persisted computed columns.

For example, I assign (arbitrarily) the value 1 for the ChildType of ChildA, 2 for ChildB, etc. (there is a CHECK constraint on ChildType)

I then create persisted columns using CASE to give the Parent table a ChildAId, ChildBId, etc by using the Type column.

that is,

```
ChildAId AS CASE WHEN ChildType=1 THEN ItemId END PERSISTED,
ChildBId AS CASE WHEN ChildType=2 THEN ItemId END PERSISTED,
```

.... etc

These computed columns are persisted, as I need to use them in `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

The contents of the various Child tables are so different as to be completely unrelated to one another.

In this way, I have effectively managed to represent a variant type in SQL

Other ideas I had considered, and why I rejected them:

1. Use the Id of the Parent table in the ChildX tables. Rejected because it allows more than one Child per Parent.
2. xref tables between Parent and the various ChildX tables. Rejected because it, too, would allow multiple children per parent (and more importantly, multiple parents per child)
3. Create a bunch of columns that represent a superset of all of the data needed for all of the child types. rejected because it is stupid (also, this is what the system I am in the process of replacing did, and one of the things I am trying to avoid)

Now to the actual question:

While this was a great idea when there were only 2 types of children, I started to get worried when it suddenly jumped up to 10. While this will likely not get as high as 50, it might get up to 25 different child types before we're done.

Also, this works really well when brought down into C# through entity framework:

Effectively a Parent row associatd with a ChildA row becomes a Parent object. It is a beautiful thing really, and one of the main reasons I picked what I picked.

Is there a more standardized way that data of this type (basically a variant) gets represented in SQL in a way that is controlled through constraints and allows me to query it and consume it with things like entity framework?  Is the addition of many fields (all but one of which will always be NULL) the trade-off cost of how I'm doing this?  Am I not seeing a red flag that I should be seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe quite common way to deal with such cases is
***1) use the Id of the Parent table in the ChildX tables*** with a slight modification

Even though it introduces redundancy, it's an acceptable cost for having clear model which enforced by the engine. For instance,

```
ParentTable(parentTableId, childType, UNIQUE(parentTableId,childType) , 
 PK(parentTableId), CHECK(childType IN (1,2,3,4,5,...)) );
ChildTable1(parentTableId, childType, other attributes, 
    FK(parentTableId, childType), PK(parentTableId, childType), CHECK(childType=1));
ChildTable2(parentTableId, childType, other attributes, 
   FK(parentTableId, childType), PK(parentTableId, childType), CHECK(childType=2));
```

If number of child types is very small, say 2-3, it's ok to have check constraint in parent table like in the example above; if you have or expect more, I'd rather create a small lookup table, `ChildType` and use a foreign key to it (this way adding a new child type won't require changing check constraint in ParentTable)...

Answer (score 1):

What you describe looks to me like inheritance. There are 3 common ways to model it, what you describe is specifically similar to *table-per-type (TPT)*.

TPT is usually modeled with your option 1, i.e. sharing the PK on the derived tables with the parent table:

```
Base(PK id, [type], attr1, attr2)
Derived1(PK/FK id, attr10, attr11)
Derived2(PF/FK id, attr20, attr21)
```

The type attribute on the base table is not really required but may help greatly because it enables you to know what a line actually is without doing a tentative join to all derived tables.

Yes, with this model you *could* insert rows in multiple derived tables. People usually don't bother. You'll notice that you cannot enforce *everything* in a DB model. a1ex07 answer is showing you that at the price of a composite PK you can enforce this if you really want to.

Since you mention EF, you'll be glad to know that it has built-in support for TPT inheritance.